# Restrict custom post type to only site administrator role

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

How can I remove this custom post type from being shown in the dashboard for non admin users?

```
/* Add Websites Custom Post Type */
add_action( 'init', 'create_website_type' );
function create_website_type() {

    register_post_type( 'website',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Websites' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Website' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Website' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Website' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit Website' ),             
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Website' ),                
                'new_item' => __( 'Add New Website' ),              
                'view' => __( 'View Website' ),         
                'view_item' => __( 'View Website' ),                    
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Websites' ),  
                'not_found' => __( 'No Websites Found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Websites found in Trash' ),                                         
            ),
            'description' => __('Websites to be shown in Resources section.'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
            'can_export' => true        
        )
    ); 
    remove_post_type_support('website','editor'); 
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`register_post_type()` accepts a parameter `capabilities` in its arguments. See `get_post_type_capabilities()` for possible values. From the comments:

> By default, seven keys are accepted as part of the capabilities array:
>
> - `edit_post`, `read_post`, and `delete_post` are meta capabilities, which are then
>     generally mapped to corresponding primitive capabilities depending on the
>     context, which would be the post being edited/read/deleted and the user or
>     role being checked. Thus these capabilities would generally not be granted
>     directly to users or roles.
> - `edit_posts` - Controls whether objects of this post type can be edited.
> - `edit_others_posts` - Controls whether objects of this type owned by other users can be edited. If the post type does not support an author, then this will behave like `edit_posts`.
> - `publish_posts` - Controls publishing objects of this post type.
> - `read_private_posts` - Controls whether private objects can be read.
>
> These four primitive capabilities are checked in core in various
>   locations. There are also seven other primitive capabilities which are
>   not referenced directly in core, except in `map_meta_cap()`, which takes
>   the three aforementioned meta capabilities and translates them into
>   one or more primitive capabilities that must then be checked against
>   the user or role, depending on the context.
>
> - `read` - Controls whether objects of this post type can be read.
> - `delete_posts` - Controls whether objects of this post type can be deleted.
> - `delete_private_posts` - Controls whether private objects can be deleted.
> - `delete_published_posts` - Controls whether published objects can be deleted.
> - `delete_others_posts` - Controls whether objects owned by other users can be can be deleted. If the post type does not support an author, then this will behave like `delete_posts`.
> - `edit_private_posts` - Controls whether private objects can be edited.
> - `edit_published_posts` - Controls whether published objects can be edited.
>
> These additional capabilities are only used in `map_meta_cap()`. Thus,
>   they are only assigned by default if the post type is registered with
>   the `'map_meta_cap'` argument set to `true` (default is `false`).

In your registration arguments add:

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'edit_post'          => 'update_core',
    'read_post'          => 'update_core',
    'delete_post'        => 'update_core',
    'edit_posts'         => 'update_core',
    'edit_others_posts'  => 'update_core',
    'delete_posts'       => 'update_core',
    'publish_posts'      => 'update_core',
    'read_private_posts' => 'update_core'
),
```

Comment: How would you do the same thing but allowing administrators and editors to access the cpt?

Comment: @drtanz Give both a custom capability, and filter `user_has_cap`. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95851/73) for an example.

Comment: Could I do it the same way you suggested, but put the manage_links capability (shared between admins and editors) instead of update_core?

Comment: @drtanz Yes, but I would use a custom capability. The link manager will be removed eventually, and you don’t know what happens to the assigned capabilities then.

Comment: I tried using manage_categories but got errors, was trying to find some capabilities unique to editors and administrators from http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table

Comment: If going for a custom capability, I know how to add the capability, but I'm not sure what kind of filtering is needed for the purpose of hiding the menu items relating to the CPT.

Comment: Note about update_core; Only Administrators of single site installations have this capabilitiy. In Multisite, only the Super Admin has thisabilities.

Answer (score -1):

For Multi site admin can use below code in functions.php:

```
/* Add Websites Custom Post Type */

function create_website_CustomPostType() {

    register_post_type( 'website',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Websites' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Website' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Website' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Website' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit Website' ),             
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Website' ),                
                'new_item' => __( 'Add New Website' ),              
                'view' => __( 'View Website' ),         
                'view_item' => __( 'View Website' ),                    
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Websites' ),  
                'not_found' => __( 'No Websites Found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Websites found in Trash' ),                                         
            ),
            'description' => __('Websites to be shown in Resources section.'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
            'can_export' => true        
        )
    ); 
}

 // if user login with administrator display custom post type else dont
add_action( 'init', function(){
     $WhatRoleUserLoginNow= wp_get_current_user()->caps;
     $StatusAdmin=$WhatRoleUserLoginNow['administrator'] ?? null;

     if( $StatusAdmin) {
          create_website_CustomPostType();
             }
 


} );
```

The above code add custom post type to all admin users in `multisite` mode and super admin and hide and forbidden for another user role like author ,editor , ... .