# Allow Editors to edit pending posts but not draft ones

Tags: php, user-roles, editor, capabilities

I have a large number of users with Editor [Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) that help to go through the post submissions. This is my current setup for this role:

[image: Editor Capabilities]

As you can see, they are allowed to `edit_posts` and `edit_others_posts` but they cannot `edit_published_posts`. This means that they can edit posts that are in *Draft* and *Pending* status.

Now, I want to restrict them to **only** be able to edit pending posts. So, they won't have the ability to touch draft posts (**unless** if they are the author of the post). Unfortunately there is no capability like `edit_pending_posts`... *there should be*.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually not hard. To add a new capability, call `WP_Roles->add_cap()`. You have to do this just once, because it will be stored in the database. So we use a plugin activation hook.

Note to other readers: All of the following code is [plugin territory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'epp_add_cap' );

/**
 * Add new capability to "editor" role.
 *
 * @wp-hook "activate_" . __FILE__
 * @return  void
 */
function epp_add_cap()
{
    global $wp_roles;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles;

    $wp_roles->add_cap( 'editor', 'edit_pending_posts' );
}
```

Now we have to filter all calls for …

```
current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->edit_post, $post->ID );
```

… because that is how WordPress checks if an user can edit a post. Internally, this will be mapped to the `edit_others_posts` capability for other authors posts.

So we have to filter `user_has_cap` and look into our new `edit_pending_posts` capability when some wants to use the `edit_post` capability.

I have included `delete_post` too, because this also a kind of an edit.

Sound complicated, but it is really simple:

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'epp_filter_cap', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Allow editing others pending posts only with "edit_pending_posts" capability.
 * Administrators can still edit those posts.
 *
 * @wp-hook user_has_cap
 * @param   array $allcaps All the capabilities of the user
 * @param   array $caps    [0] Required capability ('edit_others_posts')
 * @param   array $args    [0] Requested capability
 *                         [1] User ID
 *                         [2] Post ID
 * @return  array
 */
function epp_filter_cap( $allcaps, $caps, $args )
{
    // Not our capability
    if ( ( 'edit_post' !== $args[0] && 'delete_post' !== $args[0] )
        or empty ( $allcaps['edit_pending_posts'] )
    )
        return $allcaps;

    $post = get_post( $args[2] );


    // Let users edit their own posts
    if ( (int) $args[1] === (int) $post->post_author
        and in_array(
            $post->post_status,
            array ( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' )
        )
    )
    {
        $allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = TRUE;
    }
    elseif ( 'pending' !== $post->post_status )
    { // Not our post status
        $allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = FALSE;
    }

    return $allcaps;
}
```

Comment: I made tests and ran into a few issues. Firstly, I had `edit_posts` and `edit_others_posts` on with the new `edit_pending_posts`. I tried just having `edit_pending_posts` on without the other two and the post menu did not appear. When testing this, I found that I could add a new post, but couldn't save the draft (`You are not allowed to edit this post` notice). Did you test to save your own post in this role? Editing pending posts are fine.

Comment: @ChristineCooper This happened because `$post->post_author` is passed as a _string_, but `$args[1]` as an integer. Sometimes. **Stupid WordPress!** I fixed it by casting both to integers. And I allowed editors to edit their own published posts. If you don’t want that, remove the `return` line in the block after `// Let users edit their own posts`.

Comment: Got it! One issue remains. I tested your updated code and it worked fine! However I do not want to allow the editors to edit their published posts so I removed that `return $allcaps;` line and the same permission issue appears with the saving of draft. Why?

Comment: Just to confirm, you were referring to remove the return line under `$allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = TRUE;`? Very odd that I am experiencing this, it doesn't make sense logically that it shouldn't work for me if it does for you, here is my setup: http://i.imgur.com/X3bv9rH.png

Comment: I don’t see `edit_pending_posts` in your screenshot? That is essential.

Comment: Sorry it is ticked, just didn't include it in the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Dlc5zTV.png

Comment: Another potential issue. I noticed that Admins have all roles ticked as default, including this one, which disables admins from editing drafts etc. Is it possible to untick it for Admins? I noticed that my `User Role Editor` plugin doesn't have the option to edit Admin capabilities.

Comment: Try the [plugin Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/).