# Capability to read user's own draft post of CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities, draft

I've got a custom role called 'Gym' and custom post type (CPT) called 'Story'. Every Gym user can create a draft of a story and view their own story drafts.

My 'Story' CPT have got the following capabilities:

```
[cap] => stdClass Object(
            [edit_post] => edit_post
            [read_post] => read_post
            [delete_post] => delete_post
            [edit_posts] => edit_posts
            [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_posts
            [publish_posts] => publish_posts
            [read_private_posts] => read_private_stories
            [read] => read
            [delete_posts] => delete_posts
            [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_posts
            [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_posts
            [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_posts
            [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_posts
            [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_posts
            [create_posts] => edit_gymtopia_story
        )
```

A Gym user have the following capabilities:

```
[read] => 1
[upload_files] => 1
[edit_gymtopia_story] => 1
[read_private_stories] => 1
```

A Gym user can create a Story draft ok. However, the Gym user is unable to view his own story draft posts. I'd thought that `[read_private_posts] => read_private_stories` capability would work.. Instead I'm getting 404 page not found.

I would really appreciate any tips and help, I don't know what I'm missing.

Many thanks, Dasha

Comment: The user needs `edit_posts` to see drafts. Have you assgned that cap too?

Comment: @toscho, to confirm, does a Gym user needs both capabilities: `edit_posts` and `read_private_stories`? I find Codex page of capabilities a bit hard to read and understand completely :(

Comment: `private` is similar to `publish`. This status is always a source of confusion. :) See [this example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95851/73) for manually assigned custom capability and access restrictions.