# Enforce conditions only for draft posts using WyPiekacz, ignore pending and published posts

Tags: plugins, posts, php, post-status

I use [WyPiekacz](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wypiekacz/) to set various conditions for authors when creating posts, for example checking if the post has a featured image or how many tags that are being used. It works fine.

However, these conditions are checked every time the post is submitted for review, updated or published. I want WyPiekacz to only check the conditions **if the post is in Draft status**. How can I do that?

The problem that I am experiencing currently is that for instance an editor changes the amount of tags and updates the pending post which then fails the tag rules set in WyPiekacz and thus the post gets changed back to draft status and the editor cannot access it again. Editors are [only allowed to edit pending posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95174/allow-editors-to-edit-pending-posts-but-not-draft-ones).

Answer (score 0):

The check is invoked after a call to `get_option( 'wypiekacz_allow_skip_rules' )`.

When you filter `pre_option_wypiekacz_allow_skip_rules` and returns something different than `FALSE`, it should stop the check early. *Not tested.*

```
add_filter(
    'pre_option_wypiekacz_allow_skip_rules',
    'wpse_100503_wypiekacz_for_drafts_only'
);

function wpse_100503_wypiekacz_for_drafts_only( $bool )
{
    if ( 'draft' === get_post_status( $GLOBALS['post'] ) )
        return $bool;

    return 0;
}
```

To prevent the post status reset, something like this could work:

```
add_filter(
    'wypiekacz_check_post',
    'wpse_100503_wypiekacz_prevent_draft_reset',
    10,
    4
);

function wpse_100503_wypiekacz_prevent_draft_reset( $errors, $text, $title, $post_data )
{
    if ( empty ( $errors ) )
        return $errors;

    if ( 'pending' === $post_data->post_status )
        remove_filter( 'query', array( $GLOBALS['wp_wypiekacz'], 'kill_sql_query' ) );
}
```

But, honestly, the plugin code is a mess.

Comment: Just tested this on a pending post, it did not work unfortunately. It changed back to draft status upon rule break. Any other ideas toscho?

Comment: @ChristineCooper See my update. I am not sure if this works without side effects.

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid. It displayed `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in /functions.php on line 1627` on the post list page under the WyPiekacz Status column. Additionally, it stopped any other posts from displaying on the list. Strange!

Comment: Then try `$post_data->post_status` in my second filter.

Comment: Where in the filter? Can you please update your answer.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Done.

Comment: Gave it a test run, didn't work unfortunately. This time, no conditions were enforced. It didn't perform any checks.